# Remove a word from chrome's in-built dictionary

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

There is a word that I often need to type, but sometimes misspell.

Unfortunately, the misspelling is also another word that is in Chrome's in-built English dictionary, so it's not highlighted for me.

I hardly ever use this second word, so it'd like to remove it from the in-built dictionary or somehow otherwise highlight it. So far the only way I've come across is to rebuild Chromium from source, which I'd rather not do. Is there another, easier way?

Comment: So I think that a possible way to approach this is to rebuild chromium from source, but that seems excessive...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a answer but rather a hint.

On Linux and Chromiumn, I found `*.bdic` files under `~/.config/chromium/Dictionaries/`, like `en-US-7-1.bdic`. But they cannot be edited directly, because these are binary files

And I found a [documentation page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries) that explains that .bdic are generated from 3 other files "using the convert_dict tool in the Chromium project".

Comment: Since this isn't actually an answer, it would be more appropriate as a comment (which requires a little more rep).

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, I wanted to post it as a comment but I could not because of my rep.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a way to add or edit google chrome's dictionary words - just type in chrome://settings/editDictionary in the address bar and it will load up a dictionary to edit. check the following article for more information.

[How to Remove a Word From the Google Chrome Spelling Dictionary](http://www.howtogeek.com/246686/how-to-remove-a-word-from-the-google-chrome-spelling-dictionary/)

Comment: This is from the custom dictionary. I want to remove a word from the in-built dictionary

Comment: This does not work for my German language Chrome.

Comment: So, for instance, I would like to delete "alterative" from the default dictionary, because, although that is a valid English word, it is not a word I ever use. If I type "alterative", I misspelled "alternative".